# Convert AngularFire JSON return integer values to decimal numbers (100 is 1.00) using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, ng-grid, angularfire

I am trying to convert data that is returned from a JSON source (Firebase via AngularFire) and have it display as a dollar amount.  The data is stored in cents in the future API, which Firebase is pretending to be for early work on the User Interface.

I know that the currency filter will convert the value and truncate decimals, insert currency symbols etc..., but I need to convert the data received as well from cents (1234) to the dollar equivalent (12.34).

Sample:

```
angular.module('MyApp').factory("StoreItems", ["$firebaseObject", "$firebaseArray", "GetFireBaseObject",
    function($firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, GetFireBaseObject) {
        var StoreItemsRef = GetFireBaseObject.DataURL('StoreItems/');
        return {
            AllStores: function() {
                return $firebaseObject(StoreItemsRef);
            },
            OneStore: function(StoreKey) {
                var OneStoreRef = StoreItemsRef.child(StoreKey);
                return $firebaseObject(OneStoreRef);
            },
            OneStoreItems: function(StoreKey) {
                var OneStoreRef = StoreItemsRef.child(StoreKey);
                return $firebaseArray(OneStoreRef);
            }
        };
    }
]);

angular.module('MyApp').controller("StoreItemsCtrl", ["$scope", "StoresData", "StoreItems", 
    function($scope, StoresData, StoreItems) {
        var StoreData = {};

        $scope.StoreList = StoresData.AllStores();
        $scope.SelectedStoreKey = null;

        $scope.LoadStoreData = function(StoreKey) {
            $scope.SelectedStore = StoresData.OneStore(StoreKey);
            $scope.StoreItemData = StoreItems.OneStoreItems(StoreKey);

            StoreData = StoreItems.OneStoreItems(StoreKey);
            $scope.StoreItemsGrid.data = StoreData;
        };

        columnDefs = [
            { field: "Key", displayName: "Product Code", visible: true, groupable: false, resizable: true, sortable: true },
            { field: "UnitPrice", displayName: "Unit Price", visible: true, groupable: false, resizable: true, sortable: true, cellFilter: 'currency' },
            { field: "nForPrice", displayName: "nFor Price", visible: true, groupable: false, resizable: true, sortable: true },
            { field: "nForQuantity", displayName: "nFor Qty", visible: true, groupable: true, resizable: true, sortable: true }
        ];

        $scope.StoreItemsGrid = { 
            enableSorting: true
        };
        $scope.StoreItemsGrid.columnDefs = columnDefs;
        $scope.StoreItemsGrid.data = StoreData;
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use the currenyFilter you can create your own filter to simply divide by 100 and pass the result through the currency filter.

```
angular.module('MyApp').filter('coinCurrency', function($filter){
    var currencyFilter = $filter('currency');
    return function(input){
        return currencyFilter(input / 100);
    };
});
```

Comment: Would the only change then be to use the coinCurrency in place of the current currency filter? Where does the Input come from in the function declaration, or is this automatic?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just change 'currency' to 'coinCurrency' and the rest is automatic. Whatever the value is for the property 'UnitPrice' will be passed through the filter, then displayed. In a manually constructed angular angular expression (e.g. `{{ myValue | coinCurrency | someOtherFilter: someFilterArgument }}` ) the value on the left gets piped through each filter on the right. ngGrid does this for you in the background. You can pass data through multiple filters and also provide extra arguments for each one if necessary.

Comment: I have this working on simple pages, but as an extra directive on the ng-model of an input box, it does not seem to work.

Comment: Can you make a plunker to demonstrate what you mean? Or post some code or something.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added a full question with more detail, based on what you helped with here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335767/angularjs-enter-a-formatted-value-similar-to-a-filter-and-remove-formatting-for